# MATLAB: using 'quit' in debug mode breaks matlab.mat file

Tags: debugging, matlab

Matlab 7.12 2011a,  and I have a `finish.m` file.  When I call `quit` or `exit` from the command window under normal circumstances, all is well.  But if I'm in debug mode, working in the command window (prompt is now `K>>`)  and enter `exit` , my existing matlab.mat data file is deleted and replaced with a 1k file that Matlab cannot open.  EDIT: can't repeat this corruption.  The matlab.mat file does contain the contents of the debug environment (and nothing else).

I know the proper command to exit debug is `dbquit` .  My question is why Matlab allows me to use `exit` while I'm not in my home environment -- or why Matlab doesn't remap it to `dbquit` , to avoid this disastrous loss of data.

EDIT: here is my `finish.m` code.
    disp('Saving workspace data');
    save
     save(sprintf('mat_%s',date));

Calling `exit` while inside the debugger causes `finish.m` to save the contents of the function's workspace (rather than the parent environment).   When you tested this `exit` call, was your main environment actually saved?

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report rather than a SO question

Comment: What does your finish file do?

Comment: @SamRoberts nothing other than writing a copy of my data to a date-tagged .mat file.  `finish.m` executes just fine under normal termination of Matlab

Comment: @leamvst I may report a bug but I wanted to make sure this isn't a well-known "feature" of Matlab.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I can't reproduce this - it works fine for me, at least with a simple example. Can you share more details about exactly what code your finish.m contains, and what function you're in the middle of debugging? Or does it have this effect with all debugged functions?